# How to achieve concurrency in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose I am working in a banking domain and I have three customers say A,B,C.
`Balance of A= Rs.100 Balance of B= Rs.0 Balance of C=Rs.100`

Now both A and C are sending money to B at same time. The code for increasing the balance runs concurrently.
When A sends money to B, a call is made to DB which gets its current balance i.e Rs.0
At the same time C sends money to B and call is made to DB which also returns current balance as Rs.0.

So when control is back from DB for "A" and money is added in B's account,
it will be
`Balance=Current Balance+ Money Received`
so balance= 100.
Again when control is back from DB for "C",
balance = Rs.100 since current balance fetched by this request was also Rs.0

How to handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `UPDATE account SET balance=balance+100 WHERE userId = ?` would make sure that the balance is increased properly even in concurrent scenarios.

Only if you retrieve the balance to increase it in Java code you need to make special precautions, but that would be the more complex solution.

Comment: The thing is there are Rest apis created for getBalance() and addBalance(). So if two requests come simultaneously both will call getBalance() method and get result as 0 and then call addBalance() method with value as 100.

Comment: Well `addBalance()` isn't `setBalance()`. You don't need to know the current balance to add to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Concurrency is achieved by implementing it into the send method. So in your example there is nothing to achive, because there is already a concurrent setup. It would not be concurrent if the send commands go into a pipeline and being processed one after one.

The problem you experience is a dirty write/dirty read to/from the database Therefore a [transaction isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) is needed. Usually a database checks this circumstance and locks the row that is written to. Theoretically you could trust the database, when it offers transactions. It would be a bad practice and unnecessary to double check this. When not you should implement locks (which could get a performance problem, because of intensive locking) and synchronize the access to customer accounts.

To syncronize you could take the addBalance method:

```java
synchronized void addBalance(int amount, CustomerAccountEntity customer) {
    //getCustomerBalance
    balance = balance+amount;
}
```

Comment: Yes agreed. However wont adding synchronised block result in performance issues since it will be sequential requests coming into the system instead of parallel processing?

Comment: Yes, a synchronized method will hurt the performance a little bit, as threads have to wait for a lock to release. But the synchronzing itself is very optimized in Java, so I dont this it is as bad as one may think. As long as the connection to the database is fast (in terms of ping delay), I highly doubt that there will be a significant impact.